# How to use "awk" to execute multiple files with the same tail and export to some new files with new tails?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a folder which contain many files and each file is named as xxx.pqr which contains a protein structure record. Write a bash script to move protein in each pqr file to be centered at origin (0,0,0). Name each new file which contains relocated protein as xxxx.pqr.centered.

I used the "awk" to move the protein to where it is however I have some trouble while try to create a xxx.pqr.centered for each files, here is my code and I really have no idea about the few last words:

```
awk -v n=0 -v sumx=0 -v sumy=0 -v sumz=0 ' { if($1 == "ATOM") sumx=sumx+$6;sumy=sumy+$7;sumz=sumz+$8;n=n+1; if($1 == "ATOM") printf("%s%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%s\n", substr($0,1,30),$6-(sumx/n),$7-(sumy/n),$8-(sumz/n),substr($0,55,100))}' *.pqr > **????.centered**
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write this `awk` command in a `for` loop?

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output

Comment: The for loop work!! I just forgot that the valid in "awk "won't be read to wildcard

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, since I don't have your `.pqr` files I can't really test it but it should work (I also improved the `awk` command by consolidating and using shortened forms when needed):

`for file in /path/to/files/*.pqr
do
        awk -v n=0 -v sumx=0 -v sumy=0 -v sumz=0
        ' {
                if($1 == "ATOM") {
                        sumx+=$6;sumy+=$7;sumz+=$8;n++;
                        printf("%s%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%s\n", substr($0,1,30),$6-(sumx/n),$7-(sumy/n),$8-(sumz/n),substr($0,55,100))
                                }
          } ' $file > ${file}.centered
done`

Comment: In this case please vote up and mark as answer or at least one of them :) thanks! @ShaoSiyuan